# NullPointerException on Android Parcelable Object on Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have this problem with this piece of code and I have been a few days trying to solve it and I can't find the solution.

I have this parcelable class:

```
public class Sistema implements Parcelable{

private ArrayList<Lista> listas;
private ArrayList<Articulo> articulos;

public Sistema() {
   listas =  new ArrayList<Lista>();
   articulos =  new ArrayList<Articulo>();
}

public ArrayList<Lista> getListas() {
    return listas;
}

public void agregarLista(Lista lista) {
    this.getListas().add(lista);
}

public ArrayList<Articulo> getArticulos(){
    return this.articulos;
}

public void agregarArticulo(Articulo articulo){
    this.getArticulos().add(articulo);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Sistema> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<Sistema>() {
            @Override
            public Sistema createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
                return new Sistema(parcel);
            }

            @Override
            public Sistema[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Sistema[size];
            }
        };

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeTypedList(listas);
    parcel.writeTypedList(articulos);
}

public Sistema(Parcel parcel)
{
    parcel.readTypedList(listas, Lista.CREATOR);
    parcel.readTypedList(articulos, Articulo.CREATOR);
}
```

}

And then in the main i use an intent to send a Sistema object to an other activity:

```
public void addArticle(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AgregarArticulo.class);
        intent.putExtra("objectSystem", s);
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
```

Here is where the problem is, i recieve the intent in the second activity with this code:

```
Intent intento = getIntent();
s = intento.getParcelableExtra("objectSystem");
```

When I run the code, i get a NullPointerException in the getParcelableExtra
Do you guys have an idea of what the problem should be?
Thanks

Comment: did you try typecasting it? `s = (Sistema) intento.getParcelableExtra("objectSystem");`

Comment: also, it would be a good idea to use full package prefix for the string "objectSystem" [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)]

Comment: I tryed the typecasting and it didnt work and i dont know how to get the full package prefix for the string, how can i get that prefix? Thanks

Comment: You can look it up in your manifest file.

Comment: can you just verify that getIntent(); returns null.  maybe just System.println(String.format("intent = %s", getIntent()))

Comment: The getIntent() doesnt give me null, what gives me null is the "intento.getParcelableExtra("objectSystem"); I hope you guys can help me

Comment: Here your intent is getting Null

It's  obvious that intent is null as you are trying to access from this intent its creating NLP

try putting data in bundle and get context using `Activity`

Comment: I dont understan what you mean, could you post some code? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you please try this . You need to prefix your package name(com.example.whatever) with the name your passing in putExtra:

```
public void addArticle(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AgregarArticulo.class);
        intent.putExtra("YOURPACKAGENAME.objectSystem", s);
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
```

and same in getParcelableExtra also:

```
Intent intento = getIntent();
s = intento.getParcelableExtra("YOURPACKAGENAME.objectSystem");
```

Comment: I hope you have replaced YOURPACKAGENAME by your package name same as you declared in the manifest file of your application.